# Does jquery-ui-rails support custom themes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

[jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) sounds really helpful as it figures out all the dependencies for the UI components you want and serves up the theme css/images. However, at the end of the Github page linked to above, it talks about the limitations where only the base theme is supported. Loading other themes is apparently "cumbersome, not officially supported by this gem, and adds 1 KB overhead as both the base theme and the custom theme are served up."

Can't I just edit the base theme/images this gem uses and replace it with my own theme from jqueryui.com's ThemeRoller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your custom theme.
For example:
- delete/comment from application.css this lines

```
*= require jquery.ui.core
*= require jquery.ui.theme
```

- download theme from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
- put css file in app/assets/stylesheets/ and you can customize styles
- put images in app/assets/images/images/

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me.  After doing everything that Alexey mentioned, I had to add the following back into the application.css:

```
*= require jquery-ui.min.css
```

Obviously, I copied in the .min file into the assets/stylesheets folder from all of the files downloaded with the theme.

ME:  Rails 4.2.7, Ruby 2.2